# iAd get screwed up on ipad simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, iad

currently I'm trying to implement iAd in my universal iOS7 app.
This is working absolutly fine on iphone 
 but on the ipad i get this screwed up ads but the bannersize is correct. 
[image]

is this a known issue? or is there a ipad special implementation I didn't knew?

---

[edit!]

I'm pretty sure there is only one banner! its really just showing the normal iad ad in that weird way.
If I click on the ad, the fullscreen one is also not right scaled but its shown on the hole screen. 
Here is my implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    _adBannerView.delegate = self;
    _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBannerView];
...
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGRect contentFrame = _mainNavigation.frame, bannerFrame = CGRectZero;

    bannerFrame.size = [_adBannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

    if (_adBannerView.bannerLoaded && !_bannerIsVisible) {
        contentFrame.size.height -= bannerFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.origin.y + contentFrame.size.height;
        _bannerIsVisible = YES;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.origin.y + contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    _mainNavigation.frame = contentFrame;
    _adBannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError %@", error);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    }];
}
```

And is there a way to show the test ads on a real device? 
because I always get `"Ad inventory unavailable"`!

Comment: Are you sure that you're displaying just one iAd Banner?

Comment: @DominikHadl, yes I'm absolut sure! I've edit my question. It seems that iAds has some problems with banner and interstitial ads only on the iPad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954454/correct-way-to-implement-iad-in-ios-7-iphone-app-in-ipad/22339499?noredirect=1#comment34186142_22339499. I have no fix for that but I now use admob to display iads and this works totally fine.